# how to get the foreach loop value to next iteration php

Tags: php, mysql, logic

In my foreach loop I have the following code:

```
foreach ($qty as $count => $value) {
    if ($esc_returnbranch == 1) {
        // insert into table1 query
        $stock_return_id= $this->db->insert_id();
    } else {
        // insert into table2 query
        $purchase_return_id=$this->db->insert_id();
    }
    if ($esc_returnbranch == 1) {
        //insert into table3 query
    } else {
        //insert into table4 query
    }
}
```

Here insertion into table 1&2 nedds to perform only once and to insert into table 3 & 4 requires table 1 & 2 's insert id.
that is table 1 & 2 needs only 1 insertion but 3&4 has multiple insertions with 1& 2's id.
how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the value of your ids.

```
$stock_return_id = null;
$purchase_return_id = null;

foreach ($qty as $count => $value) {

    if ($stock_return_id == null) {
        if ($esc_returnbranch == 1) {
            // insert into table1 query
            $stock_return_id= $this->db->insert_id();
        }
    }

    if ($purchase_return_id == null) {
        if ($esc_returnbranch != 1) {
            // insert into table2 query
            $purchase_return_id=$this->db->insert_id();
        }
    }

    if ($esc_returnbranch == 1) {
        //insert into table3 query
    } else {
        //insert into table4 query
    }
}
```